# windows phone 7 progress bar for a listbox loading data

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

Is there an event I can listen for when a listbox has completed loading it's data? I have a textbox and a listbox, when the user hits enter, the listbox is populated with results from a web service. I'd like to run the progress bar while the listbox is loading and collapse it when it's finished....

**UPDATE**

```
    <controls:PivotItem Header="food" Padding="0 110 0 0">

            <Grid x:Name="ContentFood" Grid.Row="2" >

                <StackPanel>
                    ...
                    ...

                    <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Name="ppbFoods" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Width="466" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsDataLoading}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding IsDataLoading, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                        />


                    <!--Food Results-->
                    <ListBox x:Name="lbFoods" ItemsSource="{Binding Foods}" Padding="5" 
                             SelectionChanged="lbFoods_SelectionChanged" Height="480" >
                        ....
                    </ListBox>

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>


        </controls:PivotItem>
```

Here is my helper converter class....

```
    public class BoolToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T FalseValue { get; set; }
    public T TrueValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return FalseValue;
        else
            return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
    }
}

public class BoolToStringConverter : BoolToValueConverter<String> { }
public class BoolToBrushConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Brush> { }
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Visibility> { }
public class BoolToObjectConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Object> { }
```

In my App.xaml....

```
    xmlns:HelperClasses="clr-namespace:MyVirtualHealthCheck.HelperClasses"
    ...
    <HelperClasses:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed" />
```

The viewModel....

```
    ...
    public bool IsDataLoading
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    ...
    public void GetFoods(string strSearch)
    {
        IsDataLoading = true;
        WCFService.dcFoodInfoCollection localFoods = IsolatedStorageCacheManager<WCFService.dcFoodInfoCollection>.Retrieve("CurrentFoods");

            if (localFoods != null)
            {
                Foods = localFoods;
            }
            else
            {
                GetFoodsFromWCF(strSearch);
            }
    }


    public void GetFoodsFromWCF(string strSearch)
    {
        IsDataLoading = true;
        wcfProxy.GetFoodInfosAsync(strSearch);
        wcfProxy.GetFoodInfosCompleted += new EventHandler<WCFService.GetFoodInfosCompletedEventArgs>(wcfProxy_GetFoodInfosCompleted);
    }

    void wcfProxy_GetFoodInfosCompleted(object sender, WCFService.GetFoodInfosCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WCFService.dcFoodInfoCollection foods = e.Result;
        if (foods != null)
        {
            //set current foods to the results from the web service
            this.Foods = foods;
            this.IsDataLoaded = true;

            //save foods to phone so we can use cached results instead of round tripping to the web service again
            SaveFoods(foods);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Web service says: " + e.Result);
        }
        IsDataLoading = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in functionality for this. You'll have to update the progressbar when you've finished loading the data.
Alternatively update a boolean dependency property in your view model and bind the progress bar to that.

**Update**
Some rough, example code, based on comments. This is written here and not checked but you should get the idea:

The VM:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return isLoading; }

        set
        {
            isLoading = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
        }
    }

    public void SimulateLoading()
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => 
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                () => { IsLoading = false; });

        bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { IsLoading = true; });
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        };

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading}" 
                                IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsLoading}"/>
```

Set the DataContext of the page to an instance of the view model and then call `SimulateLoading()` on the view model instance.

**Update yet again**:
My mistake `IsIndeterminate` is a bool so a converter isn't required.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know how to connect the boolean property in the view model to some action on the actual page... In my mind, the view model doesn't know the page exists, right?  So the page would have to know exactly when that boolean property changes?

Comment: The listbox will be bound to a collection which will be populated in or via the viewmodel. Once the VM has finished adding items to the collection it will know to disable the progress bar. Assuming that you're using a virtualized list then you wouldn't want to wait until all items had been loaded by the listbox.

Comment: OK that's starting to make more sense to me, it sort of just happens automatically by binding the progress bar to the VM.  Do you know of source I can take a look at to help me understand how to implement this?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some sample code. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Shades of BusyIndicator! I often do this. The PerformanceProgressBar is a hypnotic animation that is quite distracting; it works very well for this purpose. The best thing about this approach is that if you collapse the list, show the PPB and request the data on another thread your UI stays responsive, and you can switch to the UI thread, bind the data, show the listbox and hide the PPB in one fast blast when the data arrives.

Comment: well done, matt.  Love the solution.  Had no idea you could bind the progress indicator like that, badass.

Comment: Matt, could you explain the following line?

 Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}

Comment: @Matt For some unknown reason, I can't get the progress bar to show up.  I tested it by hardcoding the values to true on the control and it shows up.  But the binding doesn't work...

I've updated my initial post with code.

Comment: @Jarrette updated yet again. my mistake the converter isn't needed for this. Alternatively there's a working example at http://cid-cc22250598bf7f04.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/so6346203.zip

Comment: @Matt, thanks again for all your help, that did the trick.  For some reason, when you turn IsLoading on from WITHIN the ViewModel, it doesn't work, you have to turn it on from the xaml page itself.  Yet, turning it OFF, DOES work from within the completed args method inside the ViewModel, very strange...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new form which will have a progress bar.

The Progress form will have a timer and progress bar.

```
Private Sub tProgress_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tProgress.Tick
        Count = (Count + 1) Mod ProgressBar1.Maximum
        ProgressBar1.Value = Count
    End Sub

Public Sub KillMe(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

To Call a progress form from the Main form use the following code

```
Dim ProgressThread As New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf StartProgress))
ProgressThread.Start()

Public Sub ProgressSplash()
        'Show please wait splash
        Progress = New frmProgress
        Application.Run(Progress)

End Sub
```

To close the progress form use this code

```
Public Sub CloseProgress()

        If Progress IsNot Nothing Then

            Progress.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf Progress.KillMe))
            Progress.Dispose()
            Progress = Nothing
        End If

    End Sub
```

Because Progress form runs on a different thread it won't freeze the UI.

Sorry the code is in VB.NET

Comment: thanks, VB is fine!  However, what I don't know is, how to know WHEN to close the progress bar.  There doesn't seem to be an event that tells me when the listbox has finished binding it's data...

Comment: You can call CloseProgress(); after you bind you data to the listbox. So your order should be 1. Create a Progress thread and start it 2. BindListBox() 3. CloseProgress() so that on a new thread it will display the form with progress bar and on the main thread it will still bind the data to the listbox. When binding is complete on the main thread CloseProgress call the KillMe funciton on the new thread which will close the Progress form.

Comment: But the listbox binding is done using an asynchronous call to a web service inside the viewmodel...therefore, I when I bind the listbox, there is no way of knowing when the data is completely downloaded and bound into the listbox.  The listbox is basically a list of local venues using the foursquare API.  Depending on the user's internet connection and GPS coords and the speed of the API's servers at the time, the time needed to complete the operation could vary greatly.

Comment: Your best bet is to make it a synchronous call as you will have a Progressbar showing until it's completed. Or do a thread.sleep() for the worst case scenario on the main thread.