# WP7 Loading animation for content

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, loading

I tried to find an example for content loading animation (to learn how to implement one in my app). But I couldn't find one.

What I want is: There are 4 listboxes in my mainpage and I want to show a loading animation until the listboxes have completed loading their data.

For example,IMDB application has a loading animation like I want. (You can watch it here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AV9BoyGm7Fo)

Any ideas on how to create this?

Thanks

Comment: Have u seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346203/windows-phone-7-progress-bar-for-a-listbox-loading-data

Comment: Yes, It didn't help. Maybe I shall put more effort on it one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to these links, as they seem to provide the exact solution to coding this standard loading animation:

[Creating a Splash Screen with a progress bar for WP7 applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx)

[High Performance ProgressBar for Windows Phone 7](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/)

Comment: Just be aware that the PerformanceProgressBar - despite its name - is an inferior solution. My bet is that in your case it will approximately double the wait time. More info here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Animations.aspx