# How to load data Async on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-phone-7

I am trying to load data asyncronously but on the first time, no progressbar is shown, its like the UI thread is busy calling the BackgroundWork and doesn't render the controls. What I am doing wrong?

This is the async code, inspired by this question [windows phone 7 progress bar for a listbox loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346203/windows-phone-7-progress-bar-for-a-listbox-loading-data)

```
private void Embarques_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ea) =>
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            txtUltimaAtualizacao.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        });

    bw.DoWork += (s, ea) =>
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(CarregaItens);

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `CarregaItens()` is your loading process, you shouldn't call `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` for it as that just elevates it from the background thread to the UI thread, thus freezing your app while it runs.  Just call:

`bw.DoWork += (s, ea) => CarregaItens();`

Comment: OMG! I can't believe! You solved the problem, man! And made me understand a little better this async thing. Thank you very much!